# Setting a value from database to label in Swing

Tags: java, database, swing

I am doing a swing application....

I am using 2 forms wher in  a user enters username nd password in first form,from 1st form i am connecting to servlet(in servlet, i am authenticating user and generating a unique value nd inserting this unique value into the database).In 2 form i am having a label(or textbox).
My question is how can i display the unique value(which is in database) with the label/textbox in the 2nd form.

Do i need to process from 1st form or Does there is an option in 2nd form so that i can retrive from database nd display with label/textbox.

Comment: please, this question hard to be answerable,

Comment: What exact J2SE class do you mean by 'form'?  I don't speak 'your IDE' so please translate it into Java.  If it means `JFrame`, then start with not having 2 of them.  One of the 2 should be a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`.  Note also, that word is spelled ***and***, make sure to type ***all 3*** letters of 3 letter words!

Answer (score 2):

Make a request from the 2nd form to the servlet which retrieves the value from the database. (of course, you need to have some way to be able to identify which unique value was just inserted.)
Another possiblity would be to return the newly inserted unique value after the insert as a return value. But if this is sensible/possible depends on how you make the request, the workflow of the application and the overall design...